# Python 3.7 : NameError when importing websockets module

Tags: python, websocket, nameerror

I'm having an import module issue. I'm using python 3.7.2 on windows 10.

When I trie to import the websockets module (I just write `import websockets` in the python shell), I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        + uri.__all__
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

I tried to download the websockets module last version but the error remains.

PS : English is not my native language, sorry for the phrasing

Comment: Could you share the code you are using? I just tried and have no issues.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. Windows 10, python 3.7.2 32 bit, installed websockets into clean virtual env and no error.

Comment: Same as above post

Comment: if you would like help, post the code that is throwing the error